Executing functions in PolarDB may get locked
I am a user of PolarDB. I created a logical replicatoin slot using a function, however, after executing the function, the entire database became locked. Could you please tell me what the issue is? The PostgreSQL version is 11.
SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('ttt','pgoutput'); 

I reviewed the database configuration parameters, including buffer size and concurrency settings, and found no issues. Additionally, system resource limits have not been reached.

Your final edits from the Staging Ground didn't carry over (a very annoying bug); I've redone them, hopefully correctly. Good luck!
